# Updating a variable indirectly

Tags: c, pointers

I am studying C and I've been given a task.

"Modify the program by adding a new variable that stores the address of x. Then use your variable to update (indirectly) the value of i and then print out the new value to demonstrate that your modification has worked." 
This is the code I have to modify:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i, j;
    int * p, * q;
    int ** x;

    i = 100;
    j = 200;
    p = &i;
    q = &j;
    x = &p;

    *p = *p + *q;
    *q = **x / 2;
    **x = *p + j;

    printf(" i = %d\n",   i);
    printf("&i = %p\n",  &i);
    printf(" j = %d\n",   j);
    printf("&j = %p\n",  &j);

    printf(" p = %p\n",   p);
    printf("&p = %p\n",  &p);
    printf("*p = %d\n",  *p);
    printf(" q = %p\n",   q);
    printf("&q = %p\n",  &q);
    printf("*q = %d\n",  *q);

    printf(" x = %p\n",   x);
    printf("&x = %p\n",  &x);
    printf("*x = %p\n",  *x);
    printf("**x= %d\n", **x);
    return 0;
}
```

This is what I have attempted. I declared the variable that stores the address. I then assigned it the address of x of x (newVariable) and then tried to create an increment update of address i. Compiling the program gave me the following errors:

```
ptr3.c:14:18: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     *newVariable = &x; /* Assign new variable address of x */
                  ^
ptr3.c:19:19: error: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand
     newVariable = &i++; /* Autoincrement address by 1 */
                   ^
ptr3.c:21:12: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("&newVariable = %d\n", newVariable); /* New printf statement */
        ^
```

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i, j;
    int * p, * q;
    int ** x; 
    int * newVariable; /* New variable of type address*/

    i = 100;
    j = 200;
    p = &i;
    q = &j;
    x = &p;
    newVariable = &x; /* Assign new variable address of x */

    *p = *p + *q;
    *q = **x / 2;
    **x = *p + j;
    newVariable = &i++; /* Autoincrement address by 1 */

    printf("&newVariable = %d\n", newVariable); /* New printf statement */

    printf(" i = %d\n",   i);
    printf("&i = %p\n",  &i);
    printf(" j = %d\n",   j);
    printf("&j = %p\n",  &j);

    printf(" p = %p\n",   p);
    printf("&p = %p\n",  &p);
    printf("*p = %d\n",  *p);
    printf(" q = %p\n",   q);
    printf("&q = %p\n",  &q);
    printf("*q = %d\n",  *q);

    printf(" x = %p\n",   x);
    printf("&x = %p\n",  &x);
    printf("*x = %p\n",  *x);
    printf("**x= %d\n", **x);

    return 0;
}
```

Version 3:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i, j;
    int * p, * q;
    int ** x; 
    int * newVariable; /* New variable of type address*/

    i = 100;
    j = 200;
    p = &i;
    q = &j;
    x = &p;
    newVariable = &x; /* Assign new variable address of x */

    *p = *p + *q;
    *q = **x / 2;
    **x = *p + j;
    newVariable = &i++; /* Autoincrement address by 1 */

    printf("&newVariable = %d\n", newVariable); /* New printf statement */

    printf(" i = %d\n",   i);
    printf("&i = %p\n",  &i);
    printf(" j = %d\n",   j);
    printf("&j = %p\n",  &j);

    printf(" p = %p\n",   p);
    printf("&p = %p\n",  &p);
    printf("*p = %d\n",  *p);
    printf(" q = %p\n",   q);
    printf("&q = %p\n",  &q);
    printf("*q = %d\n",  *q);

    printf(" x = %p\n",   x);
    printf("&x = %p\n",  &x);
    printf("*x = %p\n",  *x);
    printf("**x= %d\n", **x);

    return 0;
}
```

Could someone tell me what I have done wrong? I fail to see what is wrong with the program.

Comment: If NewVariable is intended to point to an integer, then it is appropriate to declare it `int *NewVariable`.  But you do not intend to have it hold the address of an integer.  It is intended to hold the address of a variable of type `int **`.  So it should be declared as `int ***NewVariable`.

Comment: There's rather a lot of code. Can you reduce the failing part down to two or three lines?

Comment: Your first error shows `*newVariable = &x;` but the line in code actually has no `*` at the beginning. Please be more exact with your code / errors analysis.

Comment: Please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  You could reduce the code considerably.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I will make sure to follow the MCVE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the  new variable will hold  the address of  `x`, it needs to  be a
pointer to the type of `x` which is `int **`. So:

```
int ***newVariable;
```

You're assigning the address of `x` correctly, with:

```
newVariable = &x;
```

To modify  `i`, let's think a  little. The original `x`  itself points
to  something  else  (in  this  case  `p`)  that  points  to  `i`.  So
the  `newVariable` adds  an  extra  level, meaning  you  just have  to
dereference it three levels to get access to `i`. If, for example, you
want to modify `i` by incrementing it you can then do it with:

```
***newVariable += 3; // increment i (indirectly) by 3
```

To print the  value of `i` you  can use itself directly,  or `p` which
points  to it,  or `x`  which points  to `p`,  or `newVariable`  which
points to `x`. So these statements will yield the same result:

```
printf("i = %d\n", i);
printf("i = %d\n", *p);
printf("i = %d\n", **x);
printf("i = %d\n", ***newVariable);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and explaining the solution step by step!

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't provide two main() functions in one file.

First problem is at newVariable definition:

```c
int ** x; /* pointer to pointer */
/* Since you want to store adress of x, you should declare pointer to pointer to pointer */
int *** newVariable; /* variable to store adress of x */
```

Second problem is on how do you indirectly increment i value:

```c
/* Since newVariable -> x -> p -> i (where "->" means "is a pointer to") */
(***newVariable)++; /* increment value of i by 1 */
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use ***newVar and point to address of x.Then you can change pointed value of newVar and show that x is also changed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i, j;
    int * p, * q;
    int ** x;
    int *** newVar;

    i = 100;
    j = 200;
    p = &i;
    q = &j;
    x = &p;
    newVar = &x;

    // prove that newVar is pointing to same as x
    printf("**x= %d\n", **x);                 //100
    ***newVar = 12345;
    printf("***newVar= %d\n", ***newVar);     //12345
    printf("**x= %d\n", **x);                 //12345
    printf("*p= %d\n", *p);                   //12345
    printf("i= %d\n", i);                     //12345

    //prove that they are all pointing to same address
    printf("p= %p\n", p);                     
    printf("*x= %p\n", *x);
    printf("**newVar= %p\n", **newVar);   


    return 0;
}
```